# How to use protractor element.all within aync/await function

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

My Code is like

```
async function myTestFunc(){
               let items:ElementArrayFinder = await element.all( by.xpath("./li"));
}
```

That code gives below error

```
'items' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Type 'any[] | ElementFinder[]' is not assignable to type 'ElementArrayFinder'.
Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementArrayFinder': browser_, getWebElements, locator_, actionResults_, and 35 more
```

Docs say "`element.all`" returns "`ElementArrayFinder`".

but when "`element.all`" used within async/await function it seems to be returning "`ElementFinder[]`".

How is that possible ?
because of this I can't use methods like "`each()`" or "`get()`" in "`ElementArrayFinder`".

What is the best possible way to use "`element.all`" within "`ElementArrayFinder`" ?

This is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of protractor are you using?  The `ElementFinder[]` syntax is used internally by protractor and must have snuck out somehow.  This was an issue in 5.2.0 but I believe it is fixed in the current version (5.4.2).  If you look at the source code, there is a change to the function that handles this, [Starting around line 550](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/c70f844a25910c63f83c6faa63fae37f3bf983e9/lib/element.ts),

```
* @param {function(Array.<ElementFinder>)} fn
* @param {function(Error)} errorFn
*
* @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A promise which will resolve to
*     an array of ElementFinders represented by the ElementArrayFinder.
*/
then<T>(
    fn?: (value: ElementFinder[] | any[]) => T | wdpromise.IThenable<T>,
    errorFn?: (error: any) => any): wdpromise.Promise<T> {
      if (this.actionResults_) {
      return this.actionResults_.then(fn, errorFn);
} else {
  return this.asElementFinders_().then(fn, errorFn);
}
}
```

Whereas it used to just be

```
@param {function(Array.<ElementFinder>)} fn
* @param {function(Error)} errorFn
*
* @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A promise which will resolve to
*     an array of ElementFinders represented by the ElementArrayFinder.
*/
then<T>(fn?: (value: ElementFinder[] | any[]) => T | wdpromise.IThenable<T>, 
errorFn?: (error: any) => any): wdpromise.Promise<T>;
```

Long story short, what version are you on and does an upgrade help?

Comment: This is my package.json
i'm using protractor 5.4.2

"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7"
  }

Comment: Darn I thought I had it.  You could try adding

`promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false` 

before your function that makes call(s) to `element.all` or `element.each`, then

`promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = true` afterwards.  I don't know if that will adversely affect your code but it might solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: `element.all` has it's own [then](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.then) function, declared separately.

So when you doing like so

```
let result = element.all();
```

You will get `ElementArrayFinder` as a result, as it specified in [Returns](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) section. `ElementArrayFinder` is an object, that has all the specified functions you wanned `get`, `each` and etc.

But if turn it into a promise,

```
let result = await element.all();
```

then it will return `A promise which will resolve to an array of ElementFinders represented by the ElementArrayFinder.` which is basically `ElementFinder[]` as specified in [Returns](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.then) section of `ElementArrayFinder.prototype.then` function.